# bash script renaming all files in current directory as well as all the directories that are above it in hierarchy?

Tags: bash

I have written following script to rename all the files within all the folders of the current directory. But I got into problem because its not only renaming the files within folder but also all the folders in current directory and parent directories in hierarchy. I realised that this is because of . and .. present in current directory. But how to get rid of them ?

```
   for i in *
    do
        cd $i
        for j in *
        do
            mv $j $i$j
        done
        cd ..
    done
```

The problem is, I have many folders and they contain images that are named as image0001 to image0100. And I want to copy all of the images to one folder. So they are overwriting each other. That is why I want to rename the images.

Comment: I don't think bash expands `.` and `..` Are you sure you're using `bash`? (`echo $BASH_VERSION`); Is `dotglob` enabled? `shopt dotglob`

Comment: Also, please add more details on how you want your files renamed.

Comment: @konsolebox I added more details to the question. And dotglob is off. Also on echoing $BASH_VERSION, I get 4.2.25(1)

Comment: you can check whether it's a directory. e.g.: `man test`

Comment: Not just `bash`; the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03) prohibits the `*` from matching an initial `.`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what's going wrong is probably that `cd $i` is sometimes failing (perhaps because `$i` is not a directory? or perhaps because it contains spaces, so triggers word splitting?), so then you stay in the same directory, and then `cd ..` moves you *up* a directory.

To fix this (and other potential issues that could crop up), I recommend making your script a bit more cautious:

```
for dir in */ ; do
    pushd "$dir" || continue
    for file in image???? ; do
        mv "./$file" "${dir%/}$file"
    done
    popd
done
```